# Resetting UITextField Left margin

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to be align Left margin of UITextField.text to 10Px. please suggest me best way ?? same in roundedRect TesxtField where text start 10 px from left

have reached almost by overriding - `(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds.` now issue is when TextField goes in to edit mode their left margin reset to Zero .......

```
@implementation UITextField(UITextFieldCatagory)

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect theRect=CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x+10, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width-10, bounds.size.height);
    return theRect;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
-(CGRect)editingRectForBounds(CGRect)bounds;
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you try UITextField's instance method [`drawTextInRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW33)?

I think you could use the `leftView` property for this.

You can add a `leftView` and `rightView` to a UITextfield. These views can be used to display an icon, but if it's an empty view it'll just take up space, which is what you want.

```
CGFloat leftInset = 5.0f;
UIView *leftView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, leftInset, self.bounds.size.height)];
self.leftView = leftView;
self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[leftView release];
```

Refer SO question [UITextField custom background view and shifting text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864487/uitextfield-custom-background-view-and-shifting-text)

Comment: do you have code for it . i guess in this i need to handle CGContextRef and i can set font ,margin everything here . would be good if you share the code please.....

Comment: You can find some sample code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274168/drop-shadow-on-uitextfield-text

Comment: Another SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754605/how-to-change-the-color-of-first-letter-of-a-textfields-text

Answer (score 2):

Override the super's implementation, and tune the results. This way you don't need to calculate with leftView and rightView (if you use them).

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect ret = [super textRectForBounds:bounds];
    ret.origin.x = ret.origin.x + 10;
    ret.size.width = ret.size.width - 20;
    return ret;
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift:

```
    let leftView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 1))
    leftView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    my_text_field.leftView = leftView;
    my_text_field.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```